# PHP is_numeric - false when Exponent in string

Tags: php

```
<?php

$val = '245E1';

var_dump($val); // return string(5) "245E1"

$n = is_numeric($val);
var_dump($n); // return bool(true)
```

**Problem**: is_numeric return **TRUE**

Questions:

1. How to treat $val as string, not a number?
2. How to disable exponent interpretation?

Comment: That is a valid number, I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: to is_numeric return FALSE, when set $val string with "E" in it.

Comment: "How to treat $val as string, not a number?" `$val = (string) '245E1'`

Comment: What kind of numbers do you want to validate? If a number has, say a hexadecimal notation, a negative sign or decimals, should the check return true then? Or must every character be a numeric character?

Comment: It is actually of type string already. `is_numeric` doesn't check the variable type.

Comment: It may be useful to explain the circumstances where this is causing you difficulty? A code example may help.

Answer (score 3):

From the manual on [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php), you'll notice there are plenty of characters that can go in:

> Numeric strings consist of optional sign, any number of digits,
>   optional decimal part and optional exponential part. Thus +0123.45e6
>   is a valid numeric value. Hexadecimal (e.g. 0xf4c3b00c), Binary (e.g.
>   0b10100111001), Octal (e.g. 0777) notation is allowed too but only
>   without sign, decimal and exponential part.

If you wish to check if a variable is type integer, you can use [is_int()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php), and for floats, you can use [is_float()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php). Note, though, that e.g. with `is_int()`, your variable must actually be of type integer, not just a numeric string. You could also use [ctype_digit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) for this, but then your variable type would have to be a string; or specifically, not an integer that matches an ASCII character's `ord()`.

It may be easiest to just use `if (preg_match('#^\d+(\.\d+)?$#', $str))` to validate your variable of which-ever type as having only digits. (Remove the expression in brackets from the pattern if optional decimals are not welcome.)

The other option is `ctype_digit((string) $str)` and casting the variable into a string type to avoid the ASCII mapping clash with integer types. This would not return true if you had decimal points.

100000 loops of `ctype_digit`: 0.0340 sec. 100000 loops of `preg_match`: 0.1120 sec. Use `ctype_digit` if you want digits only and intend to do this *a lot*. Otherwise; whatever fits your style.

Comment: Your pattern says that `1.2.3.4` is a valid numeric.

Comment: @Madara Uchiha: Yes indeed it `[\d.]+` does, thanks for the note, edited. Then, use `^\d+(\.\d+)?$` to check for digits with an optional decimal. Or make it `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` to avoid the redundant capturing of the group.

Answer (score 2):

I had some struggles with this and came up with something:

```
function is_really_numeric($string) {
  return preg_match('#^(?!0[1-9])\d*\.?(?!\.)\d+$#', $string);
}
```

And in action:

```
<?php

  $val = '245E1';

  if (preg_match('#^(?!0[1-9])\d*\.?(?!\.)\d+$#', $val)) {
    settype($val, 'float');
  }

  var_dump($val);

?>
```

This would not interpret "0123", "24e51", ".", or "1.2.3.4" as a numeric value.

https://regex101.com/r/PtPM8l/3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specifically test if it's truely an integer number (without the exponential part), you can do

```
$a = '245E1';
$b = '24';
$isNumeric = $a == (int)$a; //false
$isNumeric = $b == (int)$b; //true
$isNumeric = is_int($b) || is_string($b) && ctype_digit($b);
```

Or in general, for floating number and other cases

```
$a = '245E1';
$b = '2.4';
$isNumeric = (float)$a == $a && strlen($a) == strlen((float)$a); //false
$isNumeric = (float)$b == $b && strlen($b) == strlen((float)$b); //true
```